# What is kux file type and how to open it?

Tags: file-types, filetype

As the title says, I'm trying to open a couple files that are `kux`(there's one that's `kux#`). The origin of the files were from inner Mongolia, my friend traveled there and is now asking me how to open them.

Comment: -1 because searching youtube for kux file format, first result tells me this is a video format, known as Youku Tudou from the China region: https://datatypes.net/open-kux-files

Answer (score 0):

Your `.kux` files are older multimedia files, more precisely, files in the format of *Youku KUX Video*.

(*Youku* was a Chinese video-sharing service based in Beijing.)

This multimedia file format was some years ago popular in Asia, unfortunately it's now unsupported as an obsolete one.

But luckily, the free and open source software [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is able to convert it to many different formats — use the command

```
ffmpeg -i "Your_input_file.kux"  "Output_file.mp4"
```

to convert it into the `.mp4` video.

You may use other multimedia file extensions, as `.avi` or `.mov` instead of `.mp4` to convert your `.kux` file into those formats.

Comment: I used the command `ffmpeg -i foo.kux foo.mp4` and it resulted in an error `foo.kux: could not find codec parameters`

Answer (score 0):

Kux is a Youku video format, you can open it by downloading Youku software.
[https://pd.youku.com/?spm=a2hcb.12675304.uerCenter.5!5~5~5~A](https://pd.youku.com/?spm=a2hcb.12675304.uerCenter.5!5%7E5%7E5%7EA)

Answer (score 0):

`.kux` files are a variation of the old `.flv` format.

Regular versions of `ffmpeg` available on common OS's don't seem to be able to properly recognize and convert .kux videos, yet the the custom ffmpeg.exe version that comes with the windows Youku client *is* able to do the conversion.

If you are not on windows then in order to be able to run it you'll need to use some kind of virtualization/emulation platform like virtualbox/UTM/parallels etc. It's possible to find the custom windows builds in the wild if you google for `kux2mp4`.

Once you get your hands on youku's version of `ffmpeg.exe` you can do the conversion as outlined in the other answers:

```bash
ffmpeg.exe -i video.kux video.mp4
```